# MouseArea events on a Listview Component in QtQuick2

Tags: qml, qtquick2

We are working on a touchscreen device and we are facing an issue with the following code:

```javascript
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    id: box
    width: 360
    height: 360

    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        spacing: 0
        model: 30
        delegate: data
        clip: true
        focus: true
        smooth: true
    }
    Component{
        id: data
        Item{
            id: item
            width: list.width
            height: 30
            clip: true; smooth: true; visible: true

            property string cellColor: getCellColor(index)

            Rectangle{
                id: condData_item_line
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: cellColor
                clip: true; smooth: true
                Text{
                    text: index
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("click", index, mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    }
                    onPressed : {
                        console.log("press", index, mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    }
                    onReleased: {
                        console.log("release", index, mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    }
                    onCanceled: {
                        console.log("cancel")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getCellColor(index){
        var color;
        if(index % 2 == 0){
            color = "white";
        }else{
            color = "blue";
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

Whereas we defined handles for the `clicked` and `released` events they are never called. Is this normal? If yes, how should we code the event handling so that `clicked` and `released` events are fired on the `Rectangle` components?

Additional info: With this code, touching the first item (index:0), `clicked` and `released` events are fired properly. But touching the other items we only get `canceled` events.

Comment: Please paste code that actually runs, so we can test it out. I get the release events if I click on a delegate. What is the output for you?

Comment: I have added the whole qml code. When I touch one rectangle, it only outputs [OnPressed] then [OnCanceled]

Comment: Actually, your code works well:


    qml: press 0 176 8
    qml: release 0 176 8
    qml: click 0 176 8


Which version of Qt do you have? Are you using left click of the mouse to press the delegate?

Comment: I don't see the release event if I click and then drag - perhaps that's what you're seeing?

Comment: If you drag outside bounds it delivers the `cancel` event. Apart from that I works on my android devices. Are you on an embedded linux system?

Comment: Thank for the comments. We are working with Qt5 on an embedded linux device. Mouse clicks will produce 'click' and 'release' but with using the touch screen on the device it does not. Just simple touches, no dragging.